# Excel - Find value of range when cell is equal to x

Tags: excel

I am trying to set up a expense tracker for my family for new years.  I want to have the excel sheet give me a total for what i spent in cash, credit and check

I have a sheet set up similar to the following

[image: sample]

I want to be able to at the end of the month see what i spent in

```
cash = 100.00
check = 12400.00
credit = 494.00


I have tried the following but they do not seem to work...

* =SUM(IF(C5:C42="Cash",D5:Z42))
* =SUMIFS(D5:D45,C5:Z45,"*CASH*")
* =SUMIF(C:C,"CHECK",D5:Z43)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can do it with a multiplication, so where J2 contains the payment method

```
=SUMPRODUCT($D$2:$G$7*($C$2:$C$7=J2))
```

[image]

Comment: This also worked thanks!!

Ended up using this way as it was less work to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If the payee is coulmn "B", then:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,"check"),SUMIFS(E:E,C:C,"check"),SUMIFS(F:F,C:C,"check"),SUMIFS(G:G,C:C,"check"))
```

I modified for a table startingin coumn "B".

Comment: have coulmn b thru z that need to be checked for dollar totals.  do i need to so a sumif for every column?

Comment: Yes, I modified it accordingly.